# Loading rails environment crashes because of empty database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, crash, environment

I have an application on heroku. I've cleaned database (manually). There is no tables.

And now I have problem with running rails environment. To be precisely: the problem is absence of `users` table. The environment is needed to run `rake db:migrate`. So I cant create schema in database.

Here goes log:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `column_definitions'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:174:in `columns'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:253:in `content_columns'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts_as_relation-1.0.0/lib/active_record/acts_as_relation.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in acts_as'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts_as_relation-1.0.0/lib/active_record/acts_as_relation.rb:112:in `include'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts_as_relation-1.0.0/lib/active_record/acts_as_relation.rb:112:in `block in acts_as'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts_as_relation-1.0.0/lib/active_record/acts_as_relation.rb:111:in `class_eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts_as_relation-1.0.0/lib/active_record/acts_as_relation.rb:111:in `acts_as'
from /app/app/models/admin.rb:2:in `<class:Admin>'
  from /app/app/models/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
  from /app/app/controllers/admin/abstract_admin_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
  from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>
```

And here is Admin model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user

  strip_attributes
end
```

And User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  validates :login, :email, presence: true
  validates :login, format: { with: /\A[0-9a-z._-]{3,}\z/}
  validates :login, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([a-z0-9._%+-]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }, :if => :password
  validates :password, confirmation: true, :if => :password

  strip_attributes except: [:password, :password_confirmation]
end
```

The models listed above (I suppose) are the reason of crash. And `act_as_relation` gem maybe.

Do anyone have idea what exactly goes wrong? And how to fix it?

P.S. Funny thing: I reproduced this on my local computer and migrations work fine! No problems with rails environment. I use development database so this could be a difference.

Comment: Have you tried running `rake db:schema:load` instead?

Comment: perhaps you can try to run `heroku run pg:reset` and then after that reseed the db by using `heroku run rake db:migrate` and db:seed if necessary. Keep in mind this blows the entire db though, I'm assuming there's nothing important on there

Comment: @derekyau, to be precise: I tried `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` but it brings database to the same state (empty state).

Comment: @davogones, It caused the same exception because of eager loading mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try editing your production.rb and edit `eager_load` to false - there's a few bugs in Rails4 release that can cause these circular breakages on (initial) deployment and the try redeploying again and then run your migration.

See http://john.beynon.org.uk/2013/08/23/rails-4-and-rake-tasks-gotcha.html for another example of where this occurs.